# Configure GNOME and KDE differently

Tags: gnome, kde, themes, configuration, desktop-environments

I have Ubuntu 21.04 and recently installed KDE.

I need to configure the theme to be different o each environment.

- *use Plank only on GNOME* : **solved**
- different fonts
- different icons and theme

I installed Plank and removed the default GNOME dock. KDE has a nice dock that I want to use, but every time I log in KDE, Plank starts because I have put Plank in startup applications.

I don't want to use different users for different configurations. I need a way to have it with an script, application or anything else that can make it.

Comment: Use `[ "$DESKTOP_SESSION" = "ubuntu" ] && plank` for "Command" field in startup applications.

Comment: @pLumo just work on terminal.

Comment: @Mohammadjavad Does it work if you use `bash -c "[ \"$DESKTOP_SESSION\" = \"ubuntu\" ] && plank"`?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog It doesn't work but adding `OnlyShowIn=GNOME` in `~/.config/autostart/plank.desktop` made it work.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog it's working but there is other problems, different fonts, icons and themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decide to delete KDE, so the only answer I got is made Plank work only on Gnome:

add `OnlyShowIn=GNOME` in `~/.config/autostart/plank.desktop` file.